# What are these eyeball statues everywhere?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

Throughout the game, there are small statues with eyeballs on them. If you inspect it, Navi says something about a fairy being inside. If you whack it with your sword, it shows you the current time.

Is there something else these are useful for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These things are called [Gossip Stones](http://zeldawiki.org/Gossip_Stone). Aside from telling you the time when you sword them, they have a few behaviours:

- They act like rubber if hit by Din's Fire or the Megaton Hammer.
- They rocket into the sky and explode if bombed.
- They release a Fairy if Zelda's Lullaby, the Sun's Song, or the Song of Storms is played nearby.
- They reveal secret information (some useful, some useless) if talked to with the [Mask of Truth](http://zeldawiki.org/Mask_of_Truth) on.